# Is publishing a book around the age of 14 possible?

Tags: publishing, young-author

I'm currently in the beginning stages of writing a book. I'm not very far along (I have the lore for the universe written and about half of the outline) however I am genuinely pursuing this. I want to publish it, but I'm only 14 and I don't know how to do that exactly. Any suggestions, tips, things to avoid, etc.?

Comment: Hi Carlie, welcome to writing.se! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about the site. This is a good first question, but one that has been asked before. Please review the linked duplicate and see if it answers you question. If you are still confused you can [edit] this post or ask another question. Good luck and happy writing!

Comment: I think the youngest published author was 7 when first published.   That said, it's not a legal barrier so much as a talent one.   There's more supply of authors seeking publishers than a demand of publishers for authors.   Brace yourself for your weight in rejection letters... It's not cause your a kid... J.K. Rowling was soundly rejected when she was trying to get Philosopher's Stone published... and that's the first book series to net the author a billion dollars (Debut Novels are rather infamous for not making much money for their authors.).